# SSL3 alert read:warning:close notify

Tags: openssl

I was executing the command

openssl s_client -connect x.x.x.x:443 -status -debug

I can see that the Server is sending it's SSL cert but in the command prompt I'm getting at the end :

SSL3 alert read:warning:close notify
SSL3 alert write:warning:close notify

Is this an error message? What would it mean ?

Thank you

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Is this an error message?

No, its not.

> What would it mean ?

close_notify alert is the normal way to stop a TLS session which should be done before closing the underlying TCP connection.
See also [RFC 5246 7.2.1 Closure Alerts](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5246#page-29).

Comment: Thank you @Steffen Ullrich. Just oconfirm, but that would prove that we are able to establish first a 3-way handshake and a secure SSL/TLS channel ? Am I correct?

Comment: @adam86: I would read the RFC in a way that these alerts are only used to close an successfully established session but I would not count on it that some stack will send these alerts are also when closing a not yet fully established session. To check for a successful session look for the server finished message and if the parties exchange data after that.

Comment: @SteffenUlIrich I see your point. I started Wireshark in the same time while running the openSSL query and I could see the TCP-connection being established and next the TLS-handshake taking place, so it proves that your answer was correct. Thank you again. I highly appreciate your expertise.